# How does this "version" of the difference quotient come out?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

When we deal with partial derivatives, we extend the difference quotient for a fuction in (in this case) two variables like $f(x, y)$, defined in an open $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ (non empty). If we want to check for the differentiability with respect to $x$ and $y$ of a function at $(x_0, y_0) \in \Omega$ we need to be finite the limits

$$\partial_x f(x, y) = \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(x_0+h, y_0) - f(x_0, y_0)}{h}$$

$$\partial_y f(x, y) = \lim_{k \to 0} \dfrac{f(x_0, y_0+k) - f(x_0, y_0)}{k}$$

I recently see over here some answers about question of differentiability, and I often saw this expression

$$\lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)} \frac{[f(x_0+h,y_0+k)-f(x_0,y_0)-h(\partial_xf(x_0, y_0))-k(\partial_yf (x_0, y_0))]}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}} $$

used in the same way that is to check if $f(x, y)$ is differentiable at $(x_0, y_0)$ wrt $x$ and $y$.

Where does this come from? Is the same as the two separate difference quotients above?

Also, a conceptual question: we take an open $\Omega$ because so we are safe when computing $f(x+h, y+k)$, that is we do not have boundary problems? Or are there other rasons?

Comment: Looks like a directional derivative.

Answer (score 2):

By definition a function defined over an open set $\Omega\subset {\bf R}^2$ is differentiable at $(a,b)\in \Omega$ iff

i) $f_x$ there exists at $(a,b)$.

ii) $f_y$ there exists at $(a,b)$.

iii) If
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (a,b)}\frac{f(x,y)-f(a,b)-f_x(a,b)(x-a)-f_{y}(a,b)(y-b)}{\sqrt{(x-a)^2 +(y-b)^{2}}}=0$$

It is not enough to ensure the existence of the partial derivatives, you need to verify all the above conditions.

Comment: Thank you . Why do we need the third condition?

Comment: First it is important to stress that the given definition is merely operational (for practical purposes of the usual vector calculus problems it is useful), a more rigorous definition is of course possible. Answering your current question, conditions i) and ii) are necessary but not sufficient. The third condition stores the idea of differentiability and is not very different from the usual definition $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)−f(a)}{x−a}$ for functions real valued. About your last question, we can work with the interior point. On the boundary, we have problems.

Comment: @Numb3rs take $(x,y)\mapsto (x,-y)$ and think why this is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.